# The convergence interval of the series

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to prove whether $x=4/27$ is convergent or not for the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{3n}{2n}x^n$$

I used Raabe's test. But I got limit is 1. So the test is not valid. Please help me which test do I need to use ? Thank you

In fact, if you help me to find its convergence interval, I Will be so happy:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $a_n = \binom{3n}{2n}$. Note
$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)}{(2n+2)(2n+1)(n+1)}. $$
For the ratio test, then, we want
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1} x^{n+1}}{a_n x^n} \right| = \frac{27}{4} |x| < 1 $$
for absolute convergence.  So  the series converges absolutely on the interval $\left( -\frac{4}{27}, \frac{4}{27} \right)$.  At $x = \frac{4}{27}$, the series becomes
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(3n)!}{(2n)!n!} \frac{2^{2n}}{3^{3n}}. $$
(HINT: use the comparison test)

Comment: +1 I was about to write in comment as "Use comparison test " :)

Comment: +1 Okay I also found the series converges absolutely. But I cannot show the series converges for both $x=-4/27$ and $x=4/27$ i.e for its en points. Please can you do more clearly for both :) thanks:)  @tylerco816

Comment: @B11b At $x = -\frac{4}{27}$, use the alternating series test to find that the series converges.  For $x = \frac{4}{27}$, however, the series diverges by the comparison test.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot:)